# сравнить переменную с элементами массива на bash

Tags: bash

Сам массив небольшой(до 15 чисел). Состоит из возрастающих элементов.
Например:
`[2 7 13 14 25 37 39 42 44 56 59 60 66]`
Нужно проверить, является ли значение цифровой переменной - частью числового массива.

Comment: Ииииии, в чем проблема? Или пройтись просто циклом по массиву нельзя?

Answer (score 1):

надо перебрать все элементы массива в цикле, сравнивая каждый элемент с переменной.

например, так:

```
a=(2 7 13 14 25 37 39 42 44 56 59 60 66)

v=39

for i in ${a[@]}; do
  if [ $v -eq $i ]; then
    echo "элемент $v входит в массив"
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: Я дмуал сейчас тут бинарный поиск будет в ответе )

Comment: @pavel, ну-у, компьютеры-то нонче — бинарные, потому и предложенный поиск — вполне себе бинарный.